# Java dynamic page title

Tags: java, web-applications, dynamic

I've just been given the task of updating a web page in an enterprise java web app to include the date in the page title.

Currently the web page is a static html file - what do i need to do to get the page title to be the current date in **YYYY/MM/DD** format? Sorry I have no idea where to start!

Comment: Could you update the question to give some more details about the environment? What is the servlet container (tomcat, etc)? What libraries are already used?

Comment: @oksayt And why is the servlet container relevant to the question? If your answer is container specific, it's a bad one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert(document.title);
document.title = (new Date()) + " --- " + document.title;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Update the page title with Javascript at the body onload event.
2. Become this static HTML file into a JSP dinamic page.

Depending on your requirements, the first option will imply less changes.
With the first option, you will take the browser date, with the second, you will use the server system date. This could be important if your application is to be accessed from different time zones.

Comment: In case of second variant try looking for <%= new java.util.Date() %> and appropriate formatting function. Besides you will need to import java.util.* on a jsp page.